# How to Pass Kendo DropDownList DataTextField value to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, kendo-dropdown

I have a `Kendo DropDownList` on the `View` and I want to pass its **`DataTextField`** value to the `Controller` and then pass and them on the labels in another `View`. Although I can pass `DataValueField` values to the `Controller`, I cannot pass `DataTextField` values. I tried to apply different scenarios but I could not. Any idea? On the other hand, if it is not possible, should the `DataTextField` values be populated again on the `Controller` and return to the other `View`?

**View:**

```
@model IssueViewModel

...
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectID)
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ProjectID")
    .DataTextField("ProjectName")
    .DataValueField("ProjectId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetProjects", "Issue");
        });
    })
)
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetProjects()
{
    var projects = repository.Projects;
    return Json(projects.Select(m => new { ProjectId = m.ID, ProjectName = m.Description }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


/* I want to pass the DataTextField values to this 
method and return them to the CreateManagement view */
public ActionResult Create(IssueViewModel issueViewModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CreateManagement", issueViewModel);
}
```

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Selam Hossein. Any reply please?

Comment: If you're using `DataTextField`s rather than `DataValueField`s on the controller, so why you don't enumerate `DataTextField`s like `DataValueField`s?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Could you post a sample code please? I have really tried many ways, but I think I made mistakes and not know how to solve this?

Comment: A `<select>` only post back one element, so do you want the selected Projects `ID` or `Description` property to be posted?

Comment: For the first operation `Description' is enough for me as I will display it on the next View. However, the next View is a create view and I will need the ID values for passing to the Controller. What do you suggest?

Comment: Then you need to post the `ID` property (as your doing now). If you also need `Description` in the POST method, then you should call the database again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your help again. Why I had to use two different View such a kind of operation is that: I cannot populate the model values in case there is a problem on the controller and view returns from the controller. So, to solve this I used Ajax, but in that case I cannot pass File Attachments. Finally I have to apply this approach :(

Comment: @StephenMuecke I only call database once. The first time I just pass the Description value to display it on the next view.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but you can use ajax to upload files - [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: @StephenMuecke For Ajax upload [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) answer is really very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to this:

```
public JsonResult GetProjects()
{
    var projects = repository.Projects;
    return Json(projects.Select(m => new SelectListItem { ProjectId = m.Description, ProjectName = m.Description }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Since the `DropDownList` uses `DataTextField` for the user and uses `DataValueField` for the server communications, so you have to use `DataTextField` value for both. *Then you can use it for the next operations.*

**Edit**: if you need both values on the controller, change `JsonResult` method to :

```
return Json(projects.Select(m => new SelectListItem { ProjectId = m.Description + "," + m.ID , ProjectName = m.Description }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now you can use both in the next operations just by spiting them like:

```
var _both = value.split(',');//value: returned value from the view
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I think I will also need DataValueField for the next operation so that I pass the id for creating new record. So, will it solved that problem as well?

Comment: So do you need both values?

Comment: Yes. Actually issueViewModel retains the DataValueField values, but I am not sure if it still retains after applying the changes you suggested. Shall I try?